# Android browser multiple file upload

Tags: android, html, upload

I am trying to upload multiple images from android browser and having problems.
It seems to only allow 1 image upload at a time.
Here is the code I am using

```
<input id='image[]' name='image[]' type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

It works great on the Iphone and browsers on my computer.

Is there any way to get this working on android browsers?

Do android browsers support HTML5?

Comment: Android browser does support most html5 elements depending on your version. See this chart for more info : http://mobilehtml5.org/

Answer (score 1):

Modern Android browsers supports html5, this web browser is based on chromium, but  on android devices and OS versions this is not posible right now. It seems to be an OS limitation... I have done a lot of research and on a lot of sites talks about this limitation. Check out this link which answer you question about multiple file upload reference per OS and web browsers [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple). If you want to know about file api per OS versions chech out this [link](http://mobilehtml5.org/)

**Update**: Multiple file uploads seems to work as android 5.x using Chrome browser